# Scala no longer supports List.make, error "value make is not a member of object List"

Tags: scala

When going thru the example
http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p15.scala

```
// P15 (**) Duplicate the elements of a list a given number of times.
//     Example:
//     scala> duplicateN(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'd))
//     res0: List[Symbol] = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'b, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'c, 'c, 'c, 'c, 'd, 'd, 'd)

object P15 {
  def duplicateN[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[A] =
    ls flatMap { List.make(n, _) }
}
```

the line

```
ls flatMap { List.make(n, _) }
```

produces the compiler error

```
"value make is not a member of object List"
```

Is there another way to rewrite this?

Comment: `ls flatMap (List.fill(n) _)`

Comment: As mentioned, in the answer, it was deprecated in Scala 2.8 (2010) and removed in Scala 2.11 (2014). Note that Scala has changed *significantly* in Scala 2.8 (2010), Scala 2.11 (2014), Scala 2.13 (2019), and a *huge* change in Scala 3 (2021). As it appears, your tutorial is from before 2.8 (2010), I would really urge you to use a more modern tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make` was deprecated in `2.8.0` and removed in `2.11.x`.

You can use

```
ls flatMap { List.fill(n)(_) }
```